# Code to check difference between 2 dates and append minute with zero .?

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

1. I have 2 HTML datepickers. As soon as the user leaves 2nd datepicker with `dateInputone` I need to check weather both values are same.
2. And 2nd thing I need to check is weather time entered by the user in both the datepicker, contains minutes value as zero. If not, I need to cut the minute entered by user and append it with zero.

Below is my HTML code:

```
<input id="dateInputone" name="dateipone" type="datetime-local" step="600">

<input id="dateInputtwo" name="dateiptwo" type="datetime-local" step="600" onblur="validate_time(this.value)">
```

Below is my JavaScript code to check weather minutes is ending with *ZERO*.

```
    function validate_time(min)
    {
      var allowed_values = new Array("00");
      var minutes = min.split(':').pop();
      for(var i=0; i <= allowed_values.length; i++)
      {
      if(allowed_values[i] == minutes)
      { 
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return minutes[0] + ":00"; 
      }
   }
 }
```

Below JavaScript code to check weather both date are same

```
       var date1 = document.getElementById("dateInputone").value;
       var date2 = document.getElementById("dateInpuTwo").value;
       var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
       var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
       alert(diffDays);
```

How to merge both this script code so that I can check for both date and minutes within a single function?

Comment: @Rajesh...im asking a way to merge above javascripts code and check date and mnutes...is this possible??

Comment: @Rajesh..How?? i tried to merge but got nothing..

Answer (score 1):

```js
var date1El = document.getElementById("dateInputone");
var date2El = document.getElementById("dateInputtwo");

function validate_time(d)
{
  var allowed_values = new Array("00");
  var minutes = d.split(':');
  for(var i=0; i <= allowed_values.length; i++)
  {
    if(allowed_values[i] == minutes[1])
    { 
      return minutes[0]+':'+allowed_values[i];
    }
    else
    {
      return minutes[0]+":00"; 
    }
  }
}

function blurred(){
    var date1 = new Date(validate_time(date1El.value))
    var date2 = new Date(validate_time(date2El.value))
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
    alert(diffDays);
}
```

```html
<input id="dateInputone" name="dateipone" type="datetime-local" step="600">

<input id="dateInputtwo" name="dateiptwo" type="datetime-local" step="600" onblur="blurred()">
```

This should work, but then, there's a question - if you wish to add more "allowed_values", this code won't work properly - you'll need to return ..:00 only after for loop.
On the other hand, if all you need is to remove minutes (replace with 00), then it'll be easier to add

```
var date1 = new Date(vdate1El.value).setMinutes(0)
```

**Single function?** No problem:

```js
function validate_time()
{
  var date1El = document.getElementById("dateInputone");
  var date2El = document.getElementById("dateInputtwo");
  
  var dates = [date1El.value,date2El.value];
  dates = dates.map((d)=>{
    console.log(d,'ddd')
    var allowed_values = new Array("00");
    var minutes = d.split(':');
    console.log('mmm',minutes)
    for(var i=0; i <= allowed_values.length; i++)
    {
      if(allowed_values[i] == minutes[1])
      { 
        return minutes[0]+':'+allowed_values[i];
      }
      else
      {
        return minutes[0]+":00"; 
      }
    }
  })
  
  
    var date1 = new Date(dates[0])
    var date2 = new Date(dates[1])
    console.log(dates,date1,date2)
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
    alert(diffDays);
}
```

```html
<input id="dateInputone" name="dateipone" type="datetime-local" step="600">

<input id="dateInputtwo" name="dateiptwo" type="datetime-local" step="600" onblur="validate_time()">
```

Comment: @Mackie..thanks for ur input what i want is to merge both this script into a single function......is this possible..??